# xpath check if document contains text

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to get all XML nodes that contains specified text. For example, when searching for text "aa" in document:

```
<book>
 <content>
    aaaaaaa
    <markup/>
    bbbbbb
 </content>
 <author>
 aabbcc
 </author>
</book>
```

I should get nodes `content` and `author`.

I was trying to use XPath "//*[contains(text(), 'aa')]" but it fails when node has some subnodes that split text (like `markup` which splits `content` in above example).

Do you know how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following XPath expression:

```
"//*[text()[contains(.,'aa')]]"
```

It finds any element node that has a text node which contains "aa".

---

There is more than one text node in `content`. An expression like:

```
//*[contains(text()[1],'aa')]
```

would also return the `content` element, because then the first text node is selected.

---

By the way, if all the text nodes of `content` contained "aa":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
 <content>
    aaaaaaa
    <markup>aaa</markup>
    aaa
 </content>
 <author>
 aabbcc
 </author>
</book>
```

Your intial XPath expression would return the `content` element. It is just that in the actual XML input you show, there are at the same time text nodes of `content` that contain "aa" and others that don't.

Further, the behaviour depends on your version of XPath. More precisely, when a function that can only process a single node as an argument is handed a sequence of nodes,

- in XPath 1.0 the first item is selected from the sequence
- in Xpath 2.0 either the function is executed with all items or with the concatenation of all values

Obviously, then, you are using XPath 2.0 because in XPath 1.0 your expression would not have caused you trouble, given the XML you present. But it would rely on "aa" necessarily appearing as part of the *first* text node of `content`.

Comment: Regarding to your edit. As I understand function 'contains(set,text)' returns true if all items from 'set' contains 'text', false otherwise?

Comment: @PawełAdamski It depends on the version of XPath. I have edited my answer.